# Why Magento catalogsearch catalogsearch/result redirect to shop home page

Tags: catalogsearch, magento1.9.2.4

We have tried the product search option in shop frontend, so executed the below URl (GET method)

https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=searchvalue

Search result output are displayed properly, but URL changed to shop home page (https://www.example.com). How to resolve this case. We need to after searching don't redirect to home page.

Note: We have checked the backend `URL rewrite management` (Does not use this URL) and also checked the `.htaccess` file.

**Shop version:** *1.9.2.4*

Comment: Have you tried running reindexing and truncating url_rewrite table ?

Comment: @MilindSingh

I will check and let you know

Comment: @MilindSingh we have tried reindexing and truncating url_rewrite table, but issue does not solve.